# Is this possible to modify existing PowerShell scripts for Sitecore?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I want to modify any one of the existing default Sitecore PowerShell scripts (in the screenshot below), is there any way of doing it?

If yes, then please let me know how this can be achieved?

[image]

Comment: I think you can open them from Powershell ISE  in Sitecore.

Comment: You can but you should not. Create your own and manage in a separate location. Otherwise your next upgrade will erase your changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manage all default scripts for sure. Especially scripts, that you ask for, are located under the following item: `/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SPE/Reporting/Content Reports/Reports/Content Audit`

[image: SPE]

Choose script that you want to change, click on **Elevate session** button, enter a user password and you will see a source of script in the **Script body** field.

**UPD:** @Michael West added an important comment. You should think twice if you want to change the default script as you will erase your changes with your next SPE module upgrade. Copy the existing OOB script and update it as you need.

Comment: thanks man, this is what I was looking for.